# Is website on wordpress easy to maintain, SEO, optimize?

Tags: wordpress, web

I intend to create my own website on wordpress. But i care about these things:

- be able to maintain
- easy to SEO, quality score
- fast loading page
- adding new features later
  Can anyone evaluate about these things. Thanks

Comment: Please read the [tour]. From that document: "Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's sort of a loaded question, but I'll try to answer it as thoroughly as possible.

**Are websites built on WordPress easy to maintain?**

That depends on what you mean by "easy to maintain". In terms of updates, the answer is as long as you don't start hacking away at themes/plugins, updates are pretty much one click and done. If you mean in terms of content updates, it's as easy as you (and whatever themes/plugins you use) make it.

**Are websites built on WordPress SEO friendly?**

Again, that's not super straight forward. WordPress itself doesn't really do too much in regards to SEO beyond defining permalink structure. How SEO friendly your website is depends largely on the theme you choose. Some are built to be SEO friendly, some are just built to be pretty (read: flashy). Either way you go, there are a ton of plugins available to help you optimize your SEO on a per-page/per-post basis, and even some which can actively monitor your ranking based on a given key word.

**Are websites built on WordPress fast-loading?**

Not to sound like a broken record, but that is in large part dependent on the theme you're using. If you're building a simple blog and have mostly textual content, it will inherently be faster than a blog that's overloaded with hundreds of under optimized images on every page. Beyond that, it's partly up to you... don't use 4K images where a 64x64 thumbnail is the only thing shown, and so on. Even more important than what you build your website on is how (and where) you host it. A major roadblock in the web world is the hardware and software that a website is sitting on. If you're running a massive site on a $5/mo shared host, it's going to be slow. If you're running a tiny site on a bare-metal server, it's going to be faster... assuming you don't screw up the server configuration.

**Are websites built on WordPress easy to extend with new features?**

YES!!! There are tens of thousands of plugins available in the official plugin repository (51,344 at this precise moment) for free, and probably twice that floating around the Internet in both free (and usually open source) and commercial plugins. CodeCanyon alone currently has 5,759 commercial plugins available for WordPress.

Now... there's also a downside to that. The plethora of available plugins sounds like a great thing, right? With that many plugins out there, should be no problem finding what you're looking for! Unfortunately, while you will most likely find a plugin suitable for most use cases... you'll probably find several. And, to make matters worse, MANY plugins aren't written or supported as well as they should be. It may take some trial and error to find JUST the right plugins to do what you need, but it's 100% possible to build the perfect website on WordPress.